# How to call a synchronous method from an asynchronous method

Tags: c#, async-await

In my application there is an async method which calls an API and from the result I need to send to a queuing system. I don't need to await the result. But the method to push the message is a synchronous one. What's the best way we can implement it?
I wrote _=Task.Run(); but I got a comment to change to Task.FromResult which I think has the value of Task.Result which is not a good approach as I don't care about the result of the Task.
[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with a more complete example? Unless you've got the title backwards, I don't see what sort of issue you're having, or how "await" factors in.

Comment: _"but I got a comment to change to Task.FromResult "_ -  I would suggest then to discuss this issue with the person who made the comment.

Comment: Task.FromResult would typically be wrapping it when calling synchronously, but: if you want it synchronously: just call it - no need for Task at all. Presumably here you're using Task.Run to do things in the background

Comment: @MarcGravell I used the Task.Run so that it will be executed by another thread and I discarded because I don't want the result of that thread execution nor the main thread needs to care about it

Comment: Consider using [Task.Yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) before synchronous `DisplayInformation` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case: *just call it*. Calling a sync method from async: absolutely fine, no problem.

If the problem is you don't want to delay the async code, then any choice of `Task.Run`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, or for very long operations: `new Thread`. The fact that you don't observe the result isn't a problem, as long as it doesn't fault - so: make sure you handle any exceptions, even if that means adding your own wrapper later for a `try`/`catch`.

Comment: So you are saying not even to put the Task.Run () ? Something like this `public async Task<List<ProductCatalog>> GetAsync()
        {
            GetData();
            return await _productCatalogCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Long running method called");
        }` and for the exceptions the synchronous method have a try catch to handle faults.

Comment: @ArjunMenon it all comes down to whether you care about the result (the list of product-catalog entries); if you need the result, even asynchronously, you probably don't need to do anything except just call and await it - no task-run necessary

Comment: No. I don't care about the result. It's just fire & forget kind-off scenario

Comment: I have added a code snippet of what I have done and seems to be okay from my perspective